# No Connection To Gradle Server && The Gradle Client Was Unable To Connect in Visual Studio Code

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, gradle, gradle-plugin

I am new to Java Projects in Visual Studio Code. This is mainly for my school project. I was setting up Gradle for Java according to YouTube videos and follows the step. I just simply installed the "**Gradle for Java"** in Visual Studio Code but  I have an error. I have restarted and reconnected it but it is showing no progress. Any help will be appreciated. Cheers!

Error:
**No Connection To Gradle Server. Try Restarting The Server.**
Error:
**The Gradle Client Was Unable To Connect. Try re-connecting.**

[No Connection To Gradle Server. Try Restarting The Server
&& The Gradle Client Was Unable To Connect. Try re-connecting.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F6Tj.png)

I tried restarting my PC, Vscode and even followed the instructions to reconnect but I am not really sure what does **Restart Server** means. I would like to acquire some answers and eventually able to run Gradle on Vscode.

Comment: Have you set the correct JDK? Was [this link](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-gradle/issues/1221) helpful?

Comment: Hi! I am sorry for no update, I have figured it out and it is the configuration of JAVA_HOME in path variables. Thank you for replying to my question I really appreciated it!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you find the solution, Please consider answering it and accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Comment: Im sorry I just added the jdk path to the JAVA_HOME. I am still learning how to use Stack Overflow. Thank you for reminding me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

1. Go to the **Windows** search bar.
2. Type **"Edit the System Environment Variables"**.
3. In the **"Adavance"** tab click **"Environment Variables"**.
4. Go to **"System Variables"**.
5. Check if you have made an option for **"JAVA_HOME"**.
6. If there is no **"JAVA_HOME"**. Click **"New"** and provide the name **"JAVA_HOME"** then save it.
7. Click **"Edit"** and enter the path of your **JDK**.

**e.g C:\Program Files\Eclipse Adoptium\jdk-17.0.6.10-hotspot**

I hope it helps, Happy Coding!

Comment: In this process the JAVA_HOME contains the directory path of your JDK.