No connection to gradle server VS CODE
I get this message on my vs code anytime I open a flutter project at the bottom right of my vs code application  "No connection to gradle server try restarting the server" and no matter how many times I restart it nothing changes. I also get a message saying "Initializing Gradle Language server" at the same time and it never gets initialized
I have attached a screenshot, but I don't know how to resolve this.

Please try this :  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76841760/4373661 or this  : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-gradle/issues/137

Thanks so much
I fixed it by installing Java extension on VsCode and then pointing it to the home folder of my jdk

I already had the Java extension installed. Uninstalling and installing again worked for me.
